# Read multiple CSV files then rename files based on the filenames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently the below code reads all the csv files in the path, then saved in a list.

I want to save each dataframe with the name of the filename e.g. echo.csv

```
path = r'M:\Work\Experimental_datasets\device_ID\IoT_device_captures\packet_header_features' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=15, sep='[|]',
        skipfooter=2, engine='python', header=None, 
        names=["sum_frame_len","avg_frame_len","max_frame_len","sum_ip_len"],
        usecols=[2,3,4,5]
        )
    li.append(df)
```

The output I get is a list of dataframes - but I want each of these dataframes with the name of the filename e.g. echo

How do I access each dataframe from the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned a dictionary would be useful for this task. For example:

```
import os
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_dict = {}

for filename in all_files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=15, sep='[|]',
        skipfooter=2, engine='python', header=None, 
        names=["sum_frame_len","avg_frame_len","max_frame_len","sum_ip_len"],
        usecols=[2,3,4,5]
        )

    name = os.path.basename(filename).split('.')[0]
    df_dict[name] = df
```

What you will be left with is the dictionary `df_dict` where the keys correspond to the name of the file and the value corresponds to the data within a given file.

You can view all the keys in the dictionary with `df_dict.keys()` and select a given DataFrame with `df_dict[key]`.